# DNS A Record going back and forth, 48 hours after changing

Tags: domains, dns, ip-address, nameserver, ip-resolve

I'm moving a website but keeping the email setting for now, so I changed the A Record on the current ISP to the new IP provided by the new ISP. And it has been more than 48 hours the domain is still flipping back and forth between the two IPs.

I've kept an eye on it on https://www.whatsmydns.net/ but there's no real progress in the last 24 hours - sometimes I get only 4 servers showing the old IP sometimes I get 12.

Contacted both ISPs, both suggested just to wait longer, but this is very worrying.

Also did another check and found this result: [image]

The old IPS is TSOHost - previously Vidahost, so don't know if that's the problem.

Comment: "I've kept an eye on it on https://www.whatsmydns.net/ but there's no real progress in the last 24 hours" This is not the first step. The first step is to check authoritative nameservers (as Stephen did). Only when setup is fully checked as good on all authoritative nameservers then you can start looking at recursive nameservers. And there is no "propagation", things are not push down and depend only on the TTL of the zone (and the parent one for NS changes or glue records or negative answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two name servers:

```
$ dig NS govanhillbaths.com
govanhillbaths.com. 86400   IN  NS  ns1.vidacloud.co.uk.
govanhillbaths.com. 86400   IN  NS  ns2.vidacloud.co.uk.
```

The two name servers are returning different IP addresses for your site:

```
$ dig @ns1.vidacloud.co.uk govanhillbaths.com
govanhillbaths.com. 86400   IN  A   185.119.173.219

dig @ns2.vidacloud.co.uk govanhillbaths.com
govanhillbaths.com. 86400   IN  A   77.104.133.95
```

Changing the A record is supposed to update the record on all of your nameservers.  It didn't.  You could:

- Try changing the `A` record again and see if it updates.
- Contact your DNS host and tell them they have a problem.
- Switch your `NS` records at your domain registrar to a new DNS host that works properly.  Your new web host likely offers DNS hosting services along with your web hosting, so you could probably use their DNS.  You'd just have to copy your `MX` and `TXT` records over to keep mail working.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - that's really helpful. I thought that might be the issue but the old IPS refuses to recognise that - very typcal of TSOHost!

And that's a good suggesting re changing the NS to the new DNS Host and point MX and TXT Records back, would you think that will cause disruption in emails?

Comment: You can add all the records to the new DNS host before switching the NS records and there will be no disruption.

Comment: Thank you - I shall do that!

Comment: But don't forget to copy all your email from the old server to the new one :P

Comment: @Steve, the mail server is staying the same.  They are just changing DNS hosting.

Comment: Sigh...somehow I read in there about mail servers changing.